# Does any metric on the real numbers imply a topology with countable many open subsets?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, real-numbers

a friend of mine came up with a question wich seems to be easy at first, but after some thinking I could not come up with a solution. The question is, weather you can define a metric $d$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that the number of open sets via this metric is only countable.

My guess is that it is not possible. I thought that for any $\epsilon > 0$ the open Ball $B_{\epsilon}(x)$ should contain infinitely many other elements (at least for uncountable many real numbers $x$) so you can't just have the set with only one element as an open leading to uncountable many open subsets. But I am not quite sure if that leads to an answer, I just wanted to mention it.

I would be glad if someone is able to answer my question, thanks a lot already!

Hannes L.

Comment: Such a space would have at most countably many closed sets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a metric space, the complement of any singleton set is always open.  So if $X$ is any set equipped with a metric, there are at least $|X|$ open sets, since $X\setminus\{x\}$ is open for each $x\in X$.

Comment: Oh, of course you are right! Thank you, actually the solution was not so hard, but I somehow didn't grasp it ^^